# How to debug iOS app with time dependency

Tags: ios, debugging, time

I have iOS app that uses time to download info from data provider. Now problem is, that for some times around midnight, there is a bug in my app and data are not downloaded correctly (there is no problem with data on the server, data are correct). How can I debug this?

Solution with being awake around midnight is not very helpful, because I have only limited window when error occurs and after that, all is OK again. So, before I can pin-point what is wrong, time passes and I have to wait another day :-/

Comment: As the data seems fine, is there any possibility of recreating the environment such that you have control over the time? That would allow you to *change* the time, as well as recreate that time state more often.

Comment: Cant you change the clock time on your device? Just be forewarned... you may get some weird messages if you have upcoming scheduled appoointments in iCal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options. You can either:

Set your iPhone time manually:
Settings --> General --> Date & Time
Select Set Automatically to OFF
You will see the current time at the very bottom. Select it to show a DateTime wheel to set it to whatever you want.

The Simulator can also be adjusted my adjusting the time on your Mac.

I have run into the same situation and it has helped me.

NOTE: You will have strange things happen if they are also date driven like scheduled appointments.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to reproduce it by using the iPhone Simulator and [setting the system clock on your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14090).

If it's something like time synchronization problems between your app and the server (Amazon Web Services' API does this), then I'm afraid the only solution will likely be to stay up until midnight, or go through your code with a fine-toothed comb. That's hard, but it sometimes works.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion that would help you in these cases would be something like https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack, where you can log information to a file and email it, so you can debug issues like this even when not connected to Xcode.